# Android NDK app crashed on run on functions that not even called

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, shared-libraries, ndk-build

I am trying to build an Android app based on Miracl crypto lib (C/C++). I have added their sources and my sources to jni folder. And wrote simple call to function that loads shared_library and returns string(withoud calls to c++ functions, just returns a string). But app crashes on run
  A/libc? Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 17711

working on Windows 7/x64
Android Studio 1.1.0
Android r10d NDK

```
Application.mk 
APP_PLATFORM := android-17 
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a 
APP_STL := stlport_static

Android.mk
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

# final lib, which will depend on others
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS  := --std=c++11 -DMR_PAIRING_BLS
LOCAL_MODULE    := CryptoLib

#find all the file recursively under jni/
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/miraclsources 
LOCAL_CPP_EXTENSION := .cpp .c

LOCAL_SRC_FILES  := miraclsources/mrcore.c \
                    miraclsources/mrarth0.c \
                    miraclsources/mrarth1.c \
                    miraclsources/mrarth2.c \
                    miraclsources/mralloc.c \
                    miraclsources/mrsmall.c \
                    miraclsources/mrio1.c \
                    miraclsources/mrio2.c \
                    miraclsources/mrgcd.c \
                    miraclsources/mrjack.c \
                    miraclsources/mrxgcd.c \
                    miraclsources/mrarth3.c \
                    miraclsources/mrbits.c \
                    miraclsources/mrrand.c \
                    miraclsources/mrprime.c \
                    miraclsources/mrcrt.c \
                    miraclsources/mrscrt.c \
                    miraclsources/mrmonty.c \
                    miraclsources/mrpower.c \
                    miraclsources/mrsroot.c \
                    miraclsources/mrcurve.c \
                    miraclsources/mrfast.c \
                    miraclsources/mrshs.c \
                    miraclsources/mrshs256.c \
                    miraclsources/mrshs512.c \
                    miraclsources/mrsha3.c \
                    miraclsources/mrfpe.c \
                    miraclsources/mraes.c \
                    miraclsources/mrgcm.c \
                    miraclsources/mrlucas.c \
                    miraclsources/mrzzn2.c \
                    miraclsources/mrzzn2b.c \
                    miraclsources/mrzzn3.c \
                    miraclsources/mrzzn4.c \
                    miraclsources/mrecn2.c \
                    miraclsources/mrstrong.c \
                    miraclsources/mrbrick.c \
                    miraclsources/mrebrick.c \
                    miraclsources/mrec2m.c \
                    miraclsources/mrgf2m.c \
                    miraclsources/mrflash.c \
                    miraclsources/mrfrnd.c \
                    miraclsources/mrdouble.c \
                    miraclsources/mrround.c \
                    miraclsources/mrbuild.c \
                    miraclsources/mrflsh1.c \
                    miraclsources/mrpi.c \
                    miraclsources/mrflsh2.c \
                    miraclsources/mrflsh3.c \
                    miraclsources/mrflsh4.c \
                    miraclsources/mrmuldv_android.c \
                    miraclsources/big.cpp \
                    miraclsources/zzn.cpp \
                    miraclsources/ecn.cpp \
                    miraclsources/ec2.cpp \
                    miraclsources/flash.cpp \
                    miraclsources/crt.cpp

LOCAL_SRC_FILES  += miraclsources/zzn2.cpp \
                    miraclsources/zzn4.cpp \
                    miraclsources/zzn8.cpp \
                    miraclsources/zzn24.cpp \
                    miraclsources/bls_pair.cpp \
                    miraclsources/ecn4.cpp

LOCAL_SRC_FILES  += sample.c

FILE_LIST := $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/*.cpp)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(FILE_LIST:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%)
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
#LOCAL_ALLOW_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS := true

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

main.cpp
#include "com_testproxy_NativeInterface.h"
#include <android/log.h>

/* Header for class com_testproxy_NativeInterface */

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_testproxy_NativeInterface_getStringFromNative(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
{
       return env -> NewStringUTF("Hello from JNI");
  }


com_testproxy_NativeInterface.h
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class com_testproxy_NativeInterface */

#ifndef _Included_com_testproxy_NativeInterface
#define _Included_com_testproxy_NativeInterface
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     com_testproxy_NativeInterface
 * Method:    getStringFromNative
 * Signature: ()Ljava/lang/String;
 */
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_testproxy_NativeInterface_getStringFromNative
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif


gradle part

        ndk {
            moduleName "CryptoLib"
        }
    }

    sourceSets.main {
        jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call (call ndk-build.cmd from terminal)
        jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
    }


Java part

public class NativeInterface {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("CryptoLib");
    }

    public native String getStringFromNative();
}

NativeInterface nativeInterface = new NativeInterface();
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
        textView.setText(nativeInterface.getStringFromNative());
```

I build with command ndk-build.cmd NDK_DEBUG=1  NDK_LOG=1

```
NDK stack trace is:

04-21 19:13:27.410  17711-17711/com.testproxy A/libc? Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 17711 (com.testproxy)
04-21 19:13:27.514      186-186/? I/DEBUG? *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
04-21 19:13:27.516      186-186/? I/DEBUG? Build fingerprint: 'google/hammerhead/hammerhead:5.1/LMY47I/1767468:user/release-keys'
04-21 19:13:27.517      186-186/? I/DEBUG? Revision: '11'
04-21 19:13:27.517      186-186/? I/DEBUG? ABI: 'arm'
04-21 19:13:27.517      186-186/? I/DEBUG? pid: 17711, tid: 17711, name: com.testproxy  >>> com.testproxy <<<
04-21 19:13:27.517      186-186/? I/DEBUG? signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0
04-21 19:13:27.558      186-186/? I/DEBUG? r0 00000000  r1 00000000  r2 00000000  r3 00000000
04-21 19:13:27.560      186-186/? I/DEBUG? r4 b4a32a60  r5 b4803128  r6 b47fe7e4  r7 b6fe9396
04-21 19:13:27.561      186-186/? I/DEBUG? r8 00000004  r9 b6fee714  sl 00000001  fp bea7c734
04-21 19:13:27.562      186-186/? I/DEBUG? ip 0000000d  sp bea7c728  lr b358d820  pc b358d824  cpsr 60070010
04-21 19:13:27.564      186-186/? I/DEBUG? backtrace:
04-21 19:13:27.566      186-186/? I/DEBUG? #00 pc 00014824  /data/app/com.testproxy-1/lib/arm/libCryptoLib.so (negify(bigtype*, bigtype*)+36)
04-21 19:13:27.567      186-186/? I/DEBUG? #01 pc 00067650  /data/app/com.testproxy-1/lib/arm/libCryptoLib.so (operator-(int, Big const&)+88)
04-21 19:13:27.568      186-186/? I/DEBUG? #02 pc 0007b6f4  /data/app/com.testproxy-1/lib/arm/libCryptoLib.so (PFC::PFC(int, csprng*)+1336)
04-21 19:13:27.569      186-186/? I/DEBUG? #03 pc 000839e0  /data/app/com.testproxy-1/lib/arm/libCryptoLib.so (GeneralConstants::GeneralConstants(char*, int)+116)
04-21 19:13:27.569      186-186/? I/DEBUG? #04 pc 00084b90  /data/app/com.testproxy-1/lib/arm/libCryptoLib.so
04-21 19:13:27.570      186-186/? I/DEBUG? #05 pc 00084be4  /data/app/com.testproxy-1/lib/arm/libCryptoLib.so
04-21 19:13:27.570      186-186/? I/DEBUG? #06 pc 000015b5  /system/bin/linker (__dl__ZN6soinfo12CallFunctionEPKcPFvvE+44)
04-21 19:13:27.570      186-186/? I/DEBUG? #07 pc 00001689  /system/bin/linker (__dl__ZN6soinfo9CallArrayEPKcPPFvvEjb+140)
04-21 19:13:27.570      186-186/? I/DEBUG? #08 pc 0000185f  /system/bin/linker (__dl__ZN6soinfo16CallConstructorsEv+142)
04-21 19:13:27.570      186-186/? I/DEBUG? #09 pc 00003259  /system/bin/linker (__dl__Z9do_dlopenPKciPK17android_dlextinfo+192)
04-21 19:13:27.571      186-186/? I/DEBUG? #10 pc 00000f1d  /system/bin/linker (__dl__ZL10dlopen_extPKciPK17android_dlextinfo+24)
04-21 19:13:27.571      186-186/? I/DEBUG? #11 pc 001e102d  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::LoadNativeLibrary(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, art::Handle<art::mirror::ClassLoader>, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*)+544)
04-21 19:13:27.572      186-186/? I/DEBUG? #12 pc 00207b13  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Runtime_nativeLoad(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jstring*, _jobject*, _jstring*)+514)
04-21 19:13:27.573      186-186/? I/DEBUG? #13 pc 000797f5  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot.oat
04-21 19:13:27.910      186-186/? I/DEBUG? Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_06
04-21 19:13:27.916      724-815/? I/BootReceiver? Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_06 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
04-21 19:13:27.924      200-200/? I/Zygote? Process 17711 exited due to signal (11)
```

But i don't even call these functions. Compilation is ok, with some warnings.
How to debug it?

Comment: "#08 pc 0000185f /system/bin/linker (__dl__ZN6soinfo16CallConstructorsEv+142)" should be a hint - some native constructors are getting invoked automatically on load, and apparently are not workable.  Now that you know why they are being called, you should probably refocus on what is wrong with them.  A SIGSEGV with an address of 0 is typically an attempt to de-reference a NULL pointer.

Comment: the problem is already solved. The reason was in our library sources. Some flags of Miracl lib for 32bit build solved the problem.

Comment: @android_dev could you please share with us - which flags did you set?